# localStorage not properly storing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to save a basic key and data to local storage.

I am doing this `localStorage.setItem('theKey', 'theData');`

For some reason when I check my localStorage in chrome I just see 'theData' stored as the key and no value with it. Here is what I see:

[image]

Any ideas as to why this would be happening? This is a react app does local storage perform differently with react?

Thank you

Comment: I think you are trying to save theData variable to  local Storage. So use localStorage.setItem('theKey', theData);

Comment: Are you positively sure your line of code is being run?

Comment: Looks like it is being stored and something must be wrong with my console. After running a getItem command as mentioned below I see the proper return

Comment: @GrantKochmann, I believe the Key value container is hidden. Try to pull down the container by hovering on border-bottom of key column :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Key Value container is hidden in your console, try this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open up the web console and run the command, `localStorage.getItem('theKey')`

If you still don't see it, try setting the key with `window.localStorage.setItem('theKey', 'theData')`

Comment: This worked! So it is being stored and I guess chromes inspection console must have a bug or something at the moment

Comment: @GrantKochmann That's doubtful.  I think in your code `localStorage`, not prefixed by `window`, is *not* using the same object as `window.localStorage`.  It's some other object, and thus it isn't behaving as one might expect.

Comment: @Amy After changing the code I think you are correct. using the 'window' prefix seems to make everything work correctly but for some reason it still doesn't show up in the console correctly

Comment: @GrantKochmann Does refreshing the page make it suddenly show up?

Comment: @Amy the problem was what I've marked as the answer. I just needed to pull down the tab to see everything working correctly. Dumb mistake! Thank you for all your help

Comment: @GrantKochmann Wow!  That's the first I've seen that.  Glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 0):

Save the theData variable not 'theData' as string value.

```
localStorage.setItem('theKey', theData);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to store a string value into local storage, and it is (apparently) not getting set.  What makes you think he's *actually* trying to store a variable?  Nothing in the question gives this impression, and your answer does not explain why the string value is not getting set.

Comment: he has mentoned he just see 'theData' is  stored as the key and no value with it. I think he wanted to store the data

Comment: The string `'theData'` **is** the data.